# How AngularJS detect custom attributes? (on low level)

Tags: angularjs

We always use attribute **ng-app**

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
...
</body>
```

How code from **angular.js** detect this and install special watchers?

Maybe there's function like this?

```
function onHtmlTagEncounter(tag){
    if(tag.hasAttribute("ng-app")){
         //Scan document and do interpolation and other...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular has a [compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#compiler) which **scans the DOM** and detects and handles angular specific markup:

This markup is either defined by directives (like the `ng-app` attribute) or uses double curly braces syntax `{{ }}` which can contain expressions and filters.

A detailed description of the compiler process can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler.).

In short compilation is a recursive process which starts at same element,
detects if the element or attributes names match the name of a angular directive and then recursively scans the children of the element.

If you are interested in the inner workings of the compiler you can always study the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js). The compiler actually does not look for any hardcoded names like `ng-app`, but instead searches for directives (which are either defined by angular or by your app).

Comment: Thank you very much. But how is the compiler works? Use it document.documentElement (return (the <html> element))?

Comment: Wrong. ng-app is [a special case](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.5/src/Angular.js#L1483), not a directive.

Comment: ng-app is directive ( but not defined like the normal ones) also it is wrong to say the the compiler run before ng-app is found

Comment: @yatongen see my extended answer. Practically you are right that the compiler looks at DOM nodes and matches directives. If you look at the source you see that the compiler is a complicated beast, but still worth to study if you are interested in the inner workings. It also helps to set a breakpoint and debug it in firebug in order to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

**The accepted answer is wrong, about ng-app**

ng-app is special, it is directive but not like the normal ones (declared angular.directive), meaning no compilation+linking will happen untill ng-app is found (so no work for compiler).

Here is the definition of ng-app (or, the function that will look for it) :

You can see, that this, directive will bootsatrap the app when ng-app is found (starting then the compiler)

```
function angularInit(element, bootstrap) {
  var appElement,
      module,
      config = {};

  // The element `element` has priority over any other element
  forEach(ngAttrPrefixes, function(prefix) {
    var name = prefix + 'app';

    if (!appElement && element.hasAttribute && element.hasAttribute(name)) {
      appElement = element;
      module = element.getAttribute(name);
    }
  });
  forEach(ngAttrPrefixes, function(prefix) {
    var name = prefix + 'app';
    var candidate;

    if (!appElement && (candidate = element.querySelector('[' + name.replace(':', '\\:') + ']'))) {
      appElement = candidate;
      module = candidate.getAttribute(name);
    }
  });
  if (appElement) {
    config.strictDi = getNgAttribute(appElement, "strict-di") !== null;
    bootstrap(appElement, module ? [module] : [], config);
  }
}
```

[angular source code.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1478)

And, [here is the initial code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7b8a16b238fa3a011e502515ac0042fe4dbc421a/src/angular.suffix) to init the app with it  :

```
jqLite(document).ready(function() {
    angularInit(document, bootstrap);
  });
```